# Detailed explainations about tmTheme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, sublimetext3, textmate

The core theme system of VS Code is from TextMate (https://macromates.com/manual/en/themes)

This system is also used in Sublime text (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes_tmtheme.html)

I searched a lot about the tmTheme rules, but still confused about those details. For example I have below pPython code:

```py
import typing

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, age: typing.Optional[int] = None) -> None:
    self.age = age


mine = MyClass(10)
```

In this example code, I am confused over what `entity.name.class` and `variable.other.constant` are, so I'm not sure what color I should use when I try to create/customize my theme.

Are there any detailed docs about tmTheme?

Comment: That information is not available in the color scheme; the Syntax Definition contains the rules that determine what the text in the file means by applying scopes to them, and the color scheme just has rules that say "make entities red". If you want to know what the scopes are, put the text cursor inside the word you're interested in and use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name`

Comment: is this question the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/77332992/11107541 ? have you read my answer there? if you have read it, why wasn't it sufficient for you? what was missing?